# alter primary id field to uniqueidentifier GUID as default in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, primary-key, alter-table, uniqueidentifier

I have tables with id(primary key - int) with identity specification (1,1) .
I want to change this column to `uniqueidentifier` with default ( `newid()` ) .

What I've tried is

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN id uniqueidentifier default NEWID();
```

but I got this message

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'default'.
```

Additionally ,every tables of my database has `id` primary key column and I want to change them to `uniqueidentifier` with default `newID()` , by looping or something .

Comment: Why on earth would you want to store GUIDs as strings? SQL Server has the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER type for a reason.

Comment: do you know the name of your PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAIN?

Comment: i've edited my question , yes , it should be `uniqueidentifier` type .

Answer (score 5):

> every tables of my database has id primary key column and I want to change them to nvarchar(36) with default newID()

No. You do *not* want to make that change as no good can come of it.

You currently have a PK (Clustered, I assume) that is:

1. Compact: 4 bytes per row
2. Efficient: comparisons are simple 4-byte-value-to-4-byte-value (i.e. a binary comparison)
3. Minimally Fragmenting: new values are sequential and added to the end of the table.

You are wanting to change this to a Clustered PK that is:

1. Wide: 72 bytes *per row* (GUID is 16 bytes, which is 32 characters in string form for the hex values plus 4 dashes for 36 characters total, which is 72 bytes in UTF-16 / `NVARCHAR`).
2. Inefficient: If using `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` it is not so bad as that is still a binary comparisons, just like with `INT`, but is 16 bytes unlike `INT` which is 4. Storing this as a string is now a 36 character comparison (36 bytes in `VARCHAR` and 72 bytes in `NVARCHAR`) which is slower than the 16 byte `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`. Finally, most people storing GUIDs as strings forget to use a binary Collation (e.g. `Latin1_General_100_BIN2`) to at least make the comparisons byte-by-byte since linguistic rules aren't necessary. Using a case-insensitive Collation, or even a case-sensitive one, is definitely slower as it will apply locale-based linguistic rules.
3. Highly Fragmenting: new values are all over the place, leading to greatly increased page splits. And if you decrease `FILLFACTOR` to reduce the number of page splits, you are also reducing the performance of the index as it is spread out over a larger amount of pages.

Please keep in mind the down-stream negative effects of this change due to:

1. Clustered index keys are copied into non-clustered indexes. Assuming, again, that this PK is Clustered, then each non-clustered index on this table will have that 72 byte value copied into it. Three non-clustered indexes on this table is 72 bytes * 3 = 216 bytes plus the original 72 of the Clustered index = 288 bytes total. On the other hand, the current `INT` would only be 4 bytes * 3 = 12 bytes plus the original 4 = 16 bytes total. Per row.
2. PKs are often used by FKs, which is the PK copied into one or more other tables. 72 bytes per row is just for this table. If this PK is used in 2 other tables as a Foreign Key, then that is 72 bytes * 2 = 144 extra bytes. On the other hand the current `INT` would only be 4 bytes * 2 = 8 bytes.

   Is the FK column indexed? If yes, then that is another 72 bytes instead of 4.
3. Data pages are loaded into memory (i.e. the Buffer Pool) before their row(s) can be read and used. Larger rows and/or lower `FILLFACTOR` means more data pages are required to hold those rows. That means more time to read them from disk into memory, and obviously the more memory they will require. This need competes with other queries, plan cache, etc.

If you need to have a GUID to have a value that is know to external systems, just add a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` column and index it; you can then look it up to get the `INT` value to use for all other JOINs, etc. And, if it has to be stored as a string, then use `VARCHAR` given the only characters are `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, and `-` (`NVARCHAR` is a completely unnecessary waste of space) *and* be sure to specify a binary Collation (one ending in `_BIN2`).

But don't change the current structure.

---

Regarding the update to the question in which it was clarified that the intended datatype to change to is really `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` and not `NVARCHAR(36)`: the overall advice does not change from "do not do it". While `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` is a better choice than `NVARCHAR(36)` (smaller and comparisons are binary), it is really just a "less bad" choice more than a "better / good choice".

Answer (score 3):

There is a big problem that you have not considered:

- As far as I know you cannot remove IDENTITY from a column.
- Hence, you can only convert this column to int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0

Not good news, but you could try another approach:

- Add a new column
- Fill it with new values
- Drop PRIMARY KEY constraint.
- Drop ID column
- Rename new column as Id
- Add a PRIMARY KEY constraint on Id column

> ```
> CREATE TABLE MyTable
> (
>     Id int IDENTITY(1,1),
>     F1 int,
>     CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY (Id)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (10),(20),(30);
>
> --= Add a new column
> ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD Id2 uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NewID() NOT NULL;
>
> --= Fill new field with values
> UPDATE MyTable 
> SET    Id2 = NewID();
>
> --= Drop PRIMARY KEY
> ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable];
>
> --= Drop Id column
> ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP COLUMN Id;
>
> --= Rename Id2 column as Id
> EXEC sp_RENAME 'MyTable.Id2', 'Id', 'COLUMN';
>
> --= Add PRIMARY KEY
> ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY (Id);
>
> SELECT * FROM myTable;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> F1 | Id                                  
> -: | :-----------------------------------
> 30 | e430b87c-6fbf-43c3-a88c-00abe925c2ea
> 20 | 67e6d0ac-3bb8-4c29-b19b-501ebdc2acee
> 10 | 287117fb-0188-480f-be54-ef42cacc123a
>
> Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures.
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=04cd47a49c33743d41bb2fde85a0adea)*

Even though this works, let me try to add a new table:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE MyTable2
> (
>     Id int,
>     MyTable_Id int NOT NULL,
>     CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable2] PRIMARY KEY (Id),
>     CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable2] FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES MyTable(Id)
> );
> ```

Yes, there is a FOREIGN KEY that references Id field of MyTable. Now try to execute the script again and...

> ```
> Msg 3725 Level 16 State 0 Line 25
> The constraint 'PK_MyTable' is being referenced by table 'MyTable2', foreign key constraint 'FK_MyTable2'.
> Msg 3727 Level 16 State 0 Line 25
> Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=69160c9e921c27f280b32febc8245a26)*

Yes, bad news again, to drop a PRIMARY KEY, you should DROP all FOREIGN KEYS that references this field *before*.

I've found a good article about [how to drop and recreate all foreign keys](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/04/11/sql-server-drop-all-the-foreign-key-constraint-in-database-create-all-the-foreign-key-constraint-in-database/), perhaps you could use it on this issue.

Comment: Above code work ,  and good news , I don't have Foreign Keys that references this field .

Comment: "UPDATE MyTable SET    Id2 = NewID();" does not look required to me, as the field was previously added with NOT NULL Default Newid(). Am I wrong ?